# ASP.NET MVC WebApi: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ninject, unit-of-work

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 Application that I want to implement Unit of Work Pattern.

In my Web Project I have:

IocConfig.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;
using NinjectMVC.Data;
using NinjectMVC.Data.Contracts;
using Ninject;


namespace NinjectMVC
{
    public class IocConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterIoc(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel(); // Ninject IoC

            // These registrations are "per instance request".
            // See http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/03/ninject-life-cycle-management-or-scoping/

            kernel.Bind<RepositoryFactories>().To<RepositoryFactories>()
                .InSingletonScope();

            kernel.Bind<IRepositoryProvider>().To<RepositoryProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<INinjectMVCUow>().To<NinjectMVCUow>();

            // Tell WebApi how to use our Ninject IoC
            config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace NinjectMVC
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            // Tell WebApi to use our custom Ioc (Ninject)
            IocConfig.RegisterIoc(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);   

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }
}
```

PersonsController.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using NinjectMVC.Data.Contracts;
using NinjectMVC.Model;

namespace NinjectMVC.Controllers
{
    public class PersonsController : ApiControllerBase
    {
        public PersonsController(INinjectMVCUow uow)
        {
            Uow = uow;
        }

        #region OData Future: IQueryable<T>
        //[Queryable]
        // public IQueryable<Person> Get()
        #endregion

        // GET /api/persons
        public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
        {
            return Uow.Persons.GetAll()
                .OrderBy(p => p.FirstName);
        }

        // GET /api/persons/5
        public Person Get(int id)
        {
            var person = Uow.Persons.GetById(id);
            if (person != null) return person;
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        // OData: GET /api/persons/?firstname=\'Hans\''
        // With OData query syntax we would not need such methods
        // /api/persons/getbyfirstname?value=Joe1
        [ActionName("getbyfirstname")]
        public Person GetByFirstName(string value)
        {
            var person = Uow.Persons.GetAll()
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.FirstName.StartsWith(value));

            if (person != null) return person;
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        // Update an existing person
        // PUT /api/persons/
        public HttpResponseMessage Put(Person person)
        {
            Uow.Persons.Update(person);
            Uow.Commit();
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to surf: http://www.domain.com/Persons/Get Im getting:

**No parameterless constructor defined for this object.**

Is there any stuff I have missed? I would appreciate any help.

Here is the zip file of the project for better references:

http://filebin.ca/E6aoOkaUpbQ/NinjectMVC.zip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wep.API uses a different `IDependencyResolver` than the MVC framework.

When you use the`HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver` it only works for ApiControllers. But your `ApiControllerBase` derives from `Controller`...

So your `ApiControllerBase` should inherit from `ApiController`.

Change it in your ApiBaseController.cs:

```
public abstract class ApiControllerBase : ApiController
{
}
```

If you want to inject dependencies to regular `Controller` derived classes you need to use ( in your IocConfig):

```
System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectMvcDependencyResolver(container));
```

Note that in this case you cannot use your `NinjectDependencyResolver` because it's for `ApiControllers`.

So you need a different `NinjectMvcDependencyResolver` which should implement  `System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver`.

```
public class NinjectMvcDependencyResolver: NinjectDependencyScope,
                                           System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
        : base(kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I want to use them for normal Controller. Do you know what should I use instead of HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver? Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks just added that line but I get the following error: The type NinjectMVC.NinjectDependencyResolver does not appear to implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator. Any clue?

Comment: This took me a long time to find. Thanks for this!!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but this might be useful for someone. :)
In my case, it was missing the `DependencyResolver` on `NinjectWebCommon.cs`.
I followed this [article](http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/04/web-api-2-and-ninject-how-to-make-them-work-together/) and everything worked fine.

```
RegisterServices(kernel);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
return kernel;
```