# InvalidOperationException when creating controllers in mvc 3 app. I created anew DBMl file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3, exception, linq-to-sql

In Mvc 3 project I had a bug in myApp.designer.cs file. I could not figure out how to fix it, so I deleted .dbml file (linq to sql classes) and created new, drug and drop tables that were in it before. Project builds, but when I run it I get InvalidOperationExcaption each time the controller should be created: "Please, make sure that the controller has constructor with no parameters".  I use ninject and DependencyResolver to bind interfaces with realizations and each controller has some interface parameter.

Before i deleted the .dbml file controllers built.

Are there any ways to fix this problem?

Comment: Does your controller have a constructor with no parameters?

Comment: The following post [SO: aspmvc-ninject-no-parameterless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217636/unit-of-work-pattern-aspmvc-ninject-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for) talks about the same symptom and emphasizes some details concerning which ninject dependency resolver you are choosing to use.  I think it might help.

Comment: No, of course the controllers don't have constructors with no parameters. All was warking before I created anew DB model file. The problem relates to model

Comment: check if the names of the linq to sql object context hasn't changed. And try cleaning and then rebuilding the solution sometimes helps